# Background php file processing without AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, background-process

Working with files compiler that puts a bit of a strain on **FIRST** homepage hit until the css files are compiled thus fooling the visitor that site is slow,

I have successfully routed the function to ajax witch works very well but I cant let it go since it is bound to js and would love to do this with php

**the ajax mootools**

```
new Request({
url: linktofile... and basic responses
```

does nothing else but is accessing php file which says

```
// sitename.com/?view=custom
file_get_contents('OF_THE_website_but_different_view');
```

so how would I do this from php  was trying `exec()` , cant get to work (WAMP local) 
**CURL** , would be same as if I would do `file_get_contents()` within homepage and slows everything down again was trying to see how `proc_open()` works but I cant figure it out

so if anyone could rout me to use any php function as a fallback for ajax and call my `file_get_contents()` file in backend without slowing the homepage down.

**please do not suggest SHELL , CRON , or any other lang but PHP**

Thank you!

Comment: The ideal way of doing this is using a cron job that runs frequently, and independently from what the user is doing. Anything else is likely to hit some restriction if you are on shared hosting.

Comment: thus I say no shell , and should also say no CRON

Comment: how do u expect to accomplish what you want to do without using shell or cron

Comment: I don't expect anything I am asking if it is possible with php alone , there is this that runs senmail script in backend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626860/how-can-i-run-a-php-script-in-the-background-after-a-form-is-submitted and might be same as to what I need but I don't understand how

Answer (score 0):

Fund awesome reference

[PHP Background Process Still Affecting Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071042/php-background-process-still-affecting-page-load)

http://php.net/features.connection-handling#71172

```
header("Connection: close");
ob_start();
phpinfo();// or my page buffer previously saved in variable
$size=ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();
flush();
file_get_contents('OF_THE_website_but_different_view');
```

works like charm